# Bring systemd services up/down along with specific systemd service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, services, systemd-unit

I have systemd:

- service1.service
- service2.service
- service3.service

service1.service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Wants=service2.service service3.service
After=service2.service service3.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/scripts/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service1.service does what it should - `it brings up services 2 and 3 before ExecStart`, which is 50% what I need.
The other 50% is to bring `service2` and `service3` down, when `service1` is down, either `systemctl stop service1` or any other termination, like `SIGKILL`.

How should I configure `service2`/`service3` to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), there appear to be several options available.

The simplest may be the `PropagatesStopTo=` option:

> `PropagatesStopTo=`, `StopPropagatedFrom=`
>
> A space-separated list of one or more units to which stop requests from this unit shall be propagated to, or units from which stop requests shall be propagated to this unit, respectively. Issuing a stop request on a unit will automatically also enqueue stop requests on all units that are linked to it using these two settings.

If I set up `service1.service` like this:

```
[Unit]
Wants=service2.service service3.service
After=service2.service service3.service
PropagatesStopTo=service2.service service3.service

[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=...
```

Then `systemctl start service1` brings up `service2` and `service3`, while `systemctl stop service1` also brings down `service2` and `service3`.

You could also do something with `PartOf` or `BindsTo` but that would require changes in the dependent services (`service2` and `service3`).